# ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Не могу понять в чем конкретно заключается ошибка, но явно это связано с проблемами сетевого соединения.

```
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 162, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
```

Бот продолжает работать даже после этой ошибки, но боюсь в какой-то момент он просто может упасть. Ошибка появляется не сразу, а через часов 6, может чуть больше. Также потом через еще часов 6 опять вслед за этой вылетает точно такая же и так будет продолжаться постоянно, но бот все равно продолжает работать. Вряд ли ошибка заключается в проблеме подключения к базе данных.

Версия `python 3.9`

Answer (score 1):

Я столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой с asyncio.
Начиная с Python 3.8 они меняют цикл событий по умолчанию в Windows на ProactorEventLoop вместо SelectorEventLoop, и с ним возникают некоторые проблемы.

поэтому добавляю

```
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, попробовал вставить это в свой код и при работе с ботом все сразу ломается, создам отдельную тему для этого